# Requesting solr using python requests

Tags: python, solr, request

I'm a beginner with solr, and I'm trying to retrieve all the id of all my documents that are in my cluster.

```
http://10.126.10.10:8980/solr/cineinfo/select?fl=mom_i&q=*:*
```

When I hit this URL I got this response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">*:*</str>
<str name="fl">mom_i</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1380" start="0">
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2730232</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2034019</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2022020</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2000015</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2000025</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2100022</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2000615</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2400027</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2020029</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<int name="mom_i">2000128</int>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

I'm trying to request a solR cluster using python. So I did a function to retrieve all the mom_i:

```
def get_all_mom(number_of_document, solr_url = _solr_url):
    headers = {'content-type': "application/json" }

    json_query = {
                'query': '*:*',
                'fl':'mom_i',
                'rows': number_of_document
            }
    response  = requests.post(solr_url, data=json.dumps(json_query), headers=headers)
    response_json = response.json()
    print response_json
    return response_json
```

The problem is when I call the function I don't have the result I get in the browser I have an error message which is:

```
{u'responseHeader': {u'status': 400, u'QTime': 0, u'params': {u'json': u'{"query": "*:*", "rows": "1380"}'}}, u'error': {u'msg': u'Unknown top-level key in JSON request : fl', u'code': 400}}
```

If you guys could help me figure out where it come from.

Comment: is it mpm_i or mom_i in fl?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when retyping it it's mom_i I edited my post

Comment: json_query = {
                query: '*:*',
                fl:'mom_i',
                rows: 10
            }....try this...

Comment: json_query = {query: ':', fl:'mom_i', rows: 10 }
NameError: global name 'query' is not defined

Comment: try q instead of query

Comment: {u'responseHeader': {u'status': 400, u'QTime': 0, u'params': {u'json': u'{"q": "*:*", "rows": 1380, "fl": "mom_i"}'}}, u'error': {u'msg': u'Unknown top-level key in JSON request : q', u'code': 400}}

Comment: try mention a word instead of "\*:\*"

Comment: check this https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5YZNCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=Unknown+top-level+key+in+JSON+request&source=bl&ots=ag5bfRtxQO&sig=4Vja_qHY1aKjVQonuCVJ8MhE_DA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8zfOsqI7MAhWFMqYKHY20CosQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=Unknown%20top-level%20key%20in%20JSON%20request&f=false

Comment: Put it as an answer to close the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book link list out all the parameters that need to be sent in the json ...

It show how to add them in `JSON`

[Json API Parameter name mapping](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5YZNCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=Unknown%20top-level%20key%20in%20JSON%20request&source=bl&ots=ag5bfRtxQO&sig=4Vja_qHY1aKjVQonuCVJ8MhE_DA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8zfOsqI7MAhWFMqYKHY20CosQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=Unknown%20top-level%20key%20in%20JSON%20request&f=false)

It shows whats options are available in `JSON  API Parameter` for the `standard request parameter`.